# Fetch Data from MS Access using .NET Core

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am actually on my first experience with **.NET Core** and trying to do a simple console application to fetch data from a MS Access database, and dump it into my MySQL database.

Normally I would have used **Oledb** and fetch all the data into a datatable, then just write it in MySQL. But with **.NetCore**, we do not have **Oledb**! 
Since .NetCore is quite new, I am not able to find some example on the net, how we can do this process.

I have installed the EntityFrameworkCore nuget, but still not able to manipulate it, nor find any documentation of how to fetch the data.

Has anyone been working with .NETCore and has a sample code of how he is fetching the data?

Comment: Are you saying that you can't find anything on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/ to do with fetching data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET core and Microsoft Access, your only choice at this moment (afaik) is to use ODBC to fetch data. There's no first party EF core provider for Access databases, and the only third party one that I know of doesn't support .NET core.

Just use [`System.Data.ODBC`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.Odbc/).

See [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader?view=netcore-2.1) for how to use it.

Comment: Is ODBC supported from Linux?

Comment: Afaik yes, but the Microsoft Access ODBC driver doesn't work under Linux, thus you have to use a third-party ODBC driver. There are many to be found, both open source and commercial.

Comment: Is this Afaik a Nuget available in nuget.org? 
Cannot find it.

Comment: I've directed you to the nuget for System.Data.ODBC. ODBC drivers are not nuget packages, they're separate installs.